# Sort dictionary's keys by nested property

Tags: javascript, sorting, dictionary

I have this kind of dictionary:

```js
const recommendations =
 { '014A8C3D-FE99-4DE3-9F9F-F197A3CB270F': 
   { zL: 0.0402632597754549,
     zD: 0,
     mL: 2,
     mD: 0,
     rate: 0.02013162988772745 },
  '036EA860-FDF1-40DA-8915-A2F02241DC7D': 
   { zL: 0.0297356539387,
     zD: 0,
     mL: 1,
     mD: 0,
     rate: 0.0297356539387 },
  '4A49B2C5-62A6-494B-BE77-FBEF5C102579': 
   { zL: 0.052390243902439025,
     zD: 0,
     mL: 1,
     mD: 0,
     rate: 0.052390243902439025 },
  '640674E4-5080-4BFD-983F-330D1C9150D0': 
   { zL: 0.011376894745,
     zD: 0,
     mL: 1,
     mD: 0,
     rate: 0.011376894745 }
 }
```

Each key is a "recommendation identifier", and each value is a dictionary of recommendation's properties.

I would like to get an array of recommendation Ids, sorted by the 'rate' property (descending order):

```js
//sortedRecommendations
['4A49B2C5-62A6-494B-BE77-FBEF5C102579',
'036EA860-FDF1-40DA-8915-A2F02241DC7D',
'014A8C3D-FE99-4DE3-9F9F-F197A3CB270F',
'640674E4-5080-4BFD-983F-330D1C9150D0']
```

I guess I should first transform my dictionary (not sortable) into an array (sortable). But then I couldn't find the way to get the expected result...

Comment: You can get the `rate` associated with an id in your sort callback using `recommendations[id].rate`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could sort by `rate` property descending by getting the delta of the compairing properties.

```js
var recommendations = { '014A8C3D-FE99-4DE3-9F9F-F197A3CB270F': { zL: 0.0402632597754549, zD: 0, mL: 2, mD: 0, rate: 0.02013162988772745 }, '036EA860-FDF1-40DA-8915-A2F02241DC7D': { zL: 0.0297356539387, zD: 0, mL: 1, mD: 0, rate: 0.0297356539387 }, '4A49B2C5-62A6-494B-BE77-FBEF5C102579': { zL: 0.052390243902439025, zD: 0, mL: 1, mD: 0, rate: 0.052390243902439025 }, '640674E4-5080-4BFD-983F-330D1C9150D0': { zL: 0.011376894745, zD: 0, mL: 1, mD: 0, rate: 0.011376894745 } },
    keys = Object
        .keys(recommendations)
        .sort((a, b) => recommendations[b].rate - recommendations[a].rate);

console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```js
const recommendations =
{ '014A8C3D-FE99-4DE3-9F9F-F197A3CB270F': 
 { zL: 0.0402632597754549,
   zD: 0,
   mL: 2,
   mD: 0,
   rate: 0.02013162988772745 },
'036EA860-FDF1-40DA-8915-A2F02241DC7D': 
 { zL: 0.0297356539387,
   zD: 0,
   mL: 1,
   mD: 0,
   rate: 0.0297356539387 },
'4A49B2C5-62A6-494B-BE77-FBEF5C102579': 
 { zL: 0.052390243902439025,
   zD: 0,
   mL: 1,
   mD: 0,
   rate: 0.052390243902439025 },
'640674E4-5080-4BFD-983F-330D1C9150D0': 
 { zL: 0.011376894745,
   zD: 0,
   mL: 1,
   mD: 0,
   rate: 0.011376894745 }
};
 
var recommendationkeys = Object.keys(recommendations);

recommendationkeys.sort(function(first,second){
    return recommendations[second].rate - recommendations[first].rate;
});

console.log(recommendationkeys);
```

Comment: Note that the `sort` callback should return `0` or a value smaller or greater than `0`, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: Isn't that `true==1` is `true` and `false==0` is `true`.

Comment: And when will it return anything < `0`?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys) and [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort)

```
Object.keys(recommendations).sort((a, b) => ( recommendations[a].rate < recommendations[b].rate ? -1 : 1)); //asc

Object.keys(recommendations).sort((a, b) => ( recommendations[a].rate < recommendations[b].rate ? 1 : -1)); //desc
```

edit: a.rate is indeed undefined. recommendations[a].rate

Comment: `a.rate` and `b.rate` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: @deceze thanks My bad, on this one, had an hard time on posting with my phone, guess it's always better to test :)